# How to keep 'search filters checks' active after changing between different categories

Tags: ajax, filter, module, prestashop, categories

I'm trying to maintain the "search_filters / facets_search_wrapper" status of the checks after changing between categories, for exemple, when the user selects "size: L" and changes the category to t-shirts, keep the "size:L" check active.

I've been thinking of saving some part of the URL that identifies the selected search filters, but I don't manage to find any solution for this.

Any ideas?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use any URL parameters, think about using Local Storage where you can filter out results on DOMReady, or you can use cookies and alter results with PHP.

Facet module is completely different in PrestaShop 1.7, there i'd suggest to use cookie method, if you are working on 1.6 tho, i'd go for a JS solution.